# Можно ли добавить html класс через css?

Tags: html, css

На сайте есть огромное количество кнопок которые используют класс `btn`. Мне нужно ко всем кнопкам добавить класс `btn-outline`. Есть ли возможность добавить этот класс к `btn` через css? Я никогда не видел подобного, возможно ли такое вообще? 
Или существует другое решение? Кроме как изменять стандартный класс `btn` подобно `btn-outline`

Comment: Если вы не в курсе, то скажу, что класс можно менять через Javascript.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вам нужен скрипт. Скорее всего сайт сделан на Bootstrap и использует JQuery. В этом случае следующая строка кода добавит нужный класс ко всем элементам с классом `btn`:

```
$(".btn").addClass("btn-outline");
```

Answer (score 1):

Можна перебором через `.each`

```js
$("div.all a.btn").each(function(){
$(this).addClass("btn-online");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="all">
<a class="btn" href="#">Button</a>
<a class="btn" href="#">Button</a>
<a class="btn" href="#">Button</a>
<a class="btn" href="#">Button</a>
</div>
<div class="other">
<a class="btn" href="#">Button</a>
<a class="btn" href="#">Button</a>
<a class="btn" href="#">Button</a>
<a class="btn" href="#">Button</a>
</div>
```